# Get terminal nodes of data in tree library

Tags: r, ggplot2, tree, classification, cart

I am trying to build a [regression](/questions/tagged/regression) or [classification](/questions/tagged/classification) [tree](/questions/tagged/tree) with some test data. My goal is to know how many terminal nodes/leaves my tree has and in which terminal node new data ends up.

I am using the [tree](/questions/tagged/tree) library, because it has the option of getting the node each data point lands in as output by using `predict(tree.model, data=df, type="where")`

I created some sample data and tried this. But it seems that `predict` does not only output terminal nodes. When running my code, `predict(...)` has the factors 3 5 6 8 9. But the tree looks like

```
 1) root 700 969.900 1 ( 0.487143 0.512857 )  
   2) B < 0.339751 346 104.300 0 ( 0.965318 0.034682 )  
     4) A < 0.747861 331  13.600 0 ( 0.996979 0.003021 ) *
     5) A > 0.747861 15  17.400 1 ( 0.266667 0.733333 )  
      10) B < 0.139725 5   5.004 0 ( 0.800000 0.200000 ) *
      11) B > 0.139725 10   0.000 1 ( 0.000000 1.000000 ) *
   3) B > 0.339751 354  68.790 1 ( 0.019774 0.980226 )  
     6) A < 0.157866 8   6.028 0 ( 0.875000 0.125000 ) *
     7) A > 0.157866 346   0.000 1 ( 0.000000 1.000000 ) *
```

(the "*" marks the terminal nodes).

**Is there a possibility to only get terminal nodes? Preferably within the tree library.**

Here is my full example code, the major part is only creating the sample data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

#generating some data to test######################################
    set.seed(42)
    #category A
    x1s = rchisq(500, 5, ncp = 0)
    y1s = 1/x1s +0.1*rchisq(500, 8, ncp = 0)
    x1s = (x1s-min(x1s))/max(x1s)
    y1s = (y1s-min(y1s))/max(y1s)
    #category B
    x2s = 15-rchisq(500, 5, ncp = 0)
    y2s = 5-(2.5 -1/400*(x2s-15)^2 +0.1*rchisq(500, 8, ncp = 0))
    x2s = (x2s-min(x2s))/max(x2s)
    y2s = (y2s-min(y2s))/max(y2s)

    xs = c(x1s, x2s)
    ys = c(y1s, y2s)
    type = c(0*(1:500), 0*(1:500)+1)
    df = data.frame(type, xs, ys)
    names(df) = c("category","A","B")
    df$category = factor(df$category)



#plot the generated data##########################################
ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=B, color=category)) + geom_point(shape=1)

#seperate in training and test data
alpha = 0.7
inTrain = sample(1:nrow(df), alpha*nrow(df))
train.set = df[inTrain,]
test.set = df[-inTrain, ]

####################################################################
#use tree to predict category
library(tree)
tree.model = tree(category ~ A + B, data = train.set)
factor(predict(tree.model, data = test.set, type="where"))
tree.model
```